# コーディングスタイルについての質問はオフトピックか

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

スタック・オーバーフローには時折、コーディングスタイルについての質問が投稿されます。大別しつつ列挙すると、下のような感じです。

- 主流のスタイルや良いスタイルを問う投稿

  - [「JavaScriptのコーディング規約はどの採用が主流ですか？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/34426/19110)
  - [「引用符のガイドライン」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2950/19110)
  - [「コントロールの命名ガイドライン」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/4431/19110)
  - [「クラスベースな言語での空行について（リーダビリティ）」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/10831/19110)
  - [「autotools 向けのコーディング規約はありますか？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/11772/19110)
  - [「Laravel 5.1 でのコーディングスタイル」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/18404/19110)
- ある特定のスタイルの利点・欠点や、そのスタイルを使う理由を問う投稿

  - [「ヨーダスタイルについて」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/32214/19110)
  - [「ループの変数名で好んでi,j,…が使われる理由はなんですか」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/12895/19110)
  - [「phpのコーディングスタイルについて」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/6950/19110)
- ある特定のスタイルに従うための方法を問う投稿

  - [「RubyやRailsのコーディングチェックツールを探しています」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/189/19110)
  - [「flocssのプレフィックスについて」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/34175/19110)

プログラミング言語の規約と違い、コーディングのスタイルには複数のものが生まれがちで、しかも「どのスタイルが良いか」という議論が起こりがちだと思います。

すると、特に「主流のスタイルや良いスタイルを問う投稿」はスタック・オーバーフローでは[オフトピック](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)なのでしょうか？

---

#### 参考1

本家 Stack Overflow では、[coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/coding-style/info) というタグに

> DO NOT USE! This tag refers to an entirely opinionated subject and is therefore no longer on-topic.

と書かれています。これに関して ["Tag burnination request: coding-style"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278455/5989200) という投稿が Stack Overflow Meta にあります。

ただし、["Coding Style Guide for node.js apps?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5495984/5989200) というクローズ済みの質問が100票以上 vote され、7つの回答があり、その内の1つは100票以上 voteされているところを見ると、このあたりは本家でも歴史の流れがあるようです。

#### 参考2

スタック・オーバーフローには [可読性](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e5%8f%af%e8%aa%ad%e6%80%a7) や [coding-style](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) というタグが存在します。

Comment: 瑣末なことですが，「ダブルスタンダード」の部分については，2011年と古い投稿ですので当時は特に問題視されずたくさん upvote されたがその後 off topic とされ close された（今日では類似の質問は紛れなく off topic）という流れだと思います．歴史的な意味で残っているというか．

Comment: @Yosh ありがとうございます。該当部分を少し書き換えました。

Answer (score 5):

現時点では、多くの場合オフトピックとするしかないのかな、と思っています。

---

「お勧めの○○」や「好きな○○」を問うものでない限り、大抵の質問に対して、回答者の工夫で客観的な回答が書けるのではないかと思います。
その点で[nekketsuuu さんの回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2475/3054)に賛成です。

ただし、あくまで一般論としてです。

- どこまでが客観的事実か、に関しても意見が一致しない
- 多くの人々が自分の意見を語らずにはいられない

といった話題があります。
コーディングスタイルは、まさにこれです。

「ある特定のスタイルの利点・欠点」の回答があったとします。
それに対しては「そのような利点・欠点は無い」という反論が必ずあります。
これは周知の事ですから、「このような意見もあり、このような反対意見もある」という一段上からの回答を書けば「客観的」という事になるかも知れませんが、そこまで抑制的にはなれないでしょう。

また、誰もが意見を持てる「自転車置き場の議論」でもあり、こういった質問があれば延々とこの話題で賑わう事間違いなしです。
参考: [インデントにタブを使うことのデメリット | teratail（回答 26）](https://teratail.com/questions/10364)

このような形で賑う事を良しとするかはサイトのポリシー次第ですが、Stack OVerflow ではオフトピックだと思います。

---

そういう訳で、コーディングスタイルに関する質問は、かなり難しいですね。
注意して客観的な回答に限定される質問にしなければいけません。
[JavaScriptのコーディング規約はどの採用が主流ですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/34426/3054) はギリギリOKかなと思って再オープンに投票したのですが、コメントを見ると「主流」が何かという議論が続きそうな気配もあり、やはり駄目なのかも知れません。

Answer (score 4):

<sup>(自己回答です。他の意見があれば投稿してください）</sup>

「主流のスタイルや良いスタイルを問う投稿」は建設的な回答がしにくいという意味でオフトピック気味ですが、質問・回答の仕方によってはオントピックにすることができると思います。つまり、ただ「〇〇というスタイルは最高です！」といった意見を期待するのではなく、

> 「〇〇という理由から〇〇スタイルは現状〇〇の技術者に好まれています。〇〇という理由から〇〇では別の〇〇スタイルが使われています」

といった感じで、より客観的な方向に議論を持っていけばよいのではないか、ということです。逆に「一番良いコーディング規約を教えてください」といった質問はオフトピックだと思います。

「ある特定のスタイルの利点・欠点や、そのスタイルを使う理由を問う投稿」は、この意味で客観的な回答が可能です。また、「ある特定のスタイルに従うための方法を問う投稿」は確実にオントピックでしょう。

本家 Stack Overflow には「コーディングスタイルの質問は [SE.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) や [CR.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ならオントピックかも」と[案内](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/coding-style/info)がありますが、これらの日本語版に相当するものはまだ無いため、ある程度以上客観的にできそうならスタック・オーバーフローの質問の範囲に入っていると判断しても良いのではないでしょうか。

また、主観的な回答しかできないとしてオフトピックにした場合も、コメント等でどういう形ならオントピックになりそうかというアドバイスをすると尚良いと思います。

- 参考

  - ["Good Subjective, Bad Subjective"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
  - ["Real Questions Have Answers"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)