# 特定言語の主要なコーディング規約における決まりについての質問はオフトピック？

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

### 経緯

2018年6月、次の質問が投稿されました: [// の後ろにはスペースを入れますか？入れませんか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/44793/19110)

こちらの質問は[元々](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/44793/1)、どのプログラミング言語に関する質問なのか本文に明記されず、タグで [php](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) と指定されているのみでした。このため「主観的な答えしか集まらない」としてクローズ票が集まり始めました。確かにこのような形式の質問で言語の指定が無いと[リスト質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1381/19110)にも見え、オフトピック気味です。

その後コメントで質問者さんとの擦り合わせを行い[本文が編集され](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/44793/2)、 **「PHP において」** **「主要なコーディング規則では」** スペースを入れるか入れないのか、ということが本文に明記されました。

クローズ票が5票に達したため、2018年6月19日現在この質問はクローズされています。

### 質問

編集後の質問は、スタック・オーバーフローにおいてオフトピックでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

言語が明示されており、また「コーディングスタイルに関する」など主観的な回答ができる内容であればオントピックで問題ないと思います。

件の質問は(質問当初)タイトルと内容がまだ絞り込めておらず、単に「コメントの書き方の好き嫌い」を問うような印象を与えていたため、クローズ票を集めてしまったのだと思います(私も票を入れた一人です)。
現在はコメントでのやり取りを受けて質問文も対象がはっきりしたようなので再オープンされたようですし、タイトルも本文に合わせて私の方で見直してみました。

Answer (score 4):

<sup>(この投稿は自己回答です。私はどうもオントピックにしたがる癖があるため、他の方のご意見も伺いたいと思っています。)</sup>

今回の場合は、オントピックで良いのではないかと思います。

コーディング規約に関する質問がオントピックなのかオフトピックなのかという問題は判断しにくいです。過去のメタ投稿[「コーディングスタイルについての質問はオフトピックか」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2474/19110)においても場合に分けて議論をしています。

今回のご質問の場合、論点となるのはどのコーディング規約なのか指定されていないことだと思います。どのコーディング規約を選ぶのかに主観性が入りえます。

ただ、話を PHP に限定した場合話題の範囲が狭くなり、今回のご質問の内容に対しては裏付けも充分とれそうなので、[建設的な主観的回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1485/19110)ができるのではないかと私は思いました。

Comment: 過去の議論もあり再オープンは迷ったのですが、nekketsuuuさんのフォローである程度回答は絞れそうだと思い投票しました。「どうすればオープンになるのか？」を考えることは悪いことではないと思います。SOに慣れていない質問者としては「プログラミングのことを聞いているのにオフトピック？」となってしまうかとおもいますので、やはりクローズ後のフォローは欲しく思いますが…。

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうですね、確かに今回はグレーラインだったこともあり、クローズ後のフォローをもう少ししっかりすべきでした。今後はそうします。